# How to change nearest neighbors function to not work diagonally

Tags: python, python-2.7, nearest-neighbor

I've working nearest neighbors function but I don't know how to make it work only horizontally and vertically right now it works in all directions. Code below:

```
nnlst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

MAP_WIDTH = 3
MAP_HEIGHT = 3


def nearest_neighbors(map_x, map_y):
    coordinates_list = []
    for x_ in range(max(0, map_x - 1), min(MAP_WIDTH, map_x + 2)):
        for y_ in range(max(0, map_y - 1), min(MAP_HEIGHT, map_y + 2)):
            # we are ignoring result when x_ and y_ equals variable we ask for
            if (map_x, map_y) == (x_, y_):
                continue
            coordinates_list.append([x_, y_])
    return coordinates_list

print "function result"
print "nearest neighbors of", nnlst[0][1]
nearest_neighbor_coordinates_list = nearest_neighbors(0, 1)

for coordinates in nearest_neighbor_coordinates_list:
    print coordinates, "=", nnlst[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]]
```

As you can see right now it works in all directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more condition to prevent inclusion of the diagonal ones:

```
def nearest_neighbors(map_x, map_y):
    coordinates_list = []
    for x_ in range(max(0, map_x - 1), min(MAP_WIDTH, map_x + 2)):
        for y_ in range(max(0, map_y - 1), min(MAP_HEIGHT, map_y + 2)):
            # we are ignoring result when x_ and y_ equals variable we ask for, also the diagonal neigbors that differ in both x & y coordinates
            if (map_x, map_y) == (x_, y_) or (map_x != x_ and map_y != y_):
                continue
            coordinates_list.append([x_, y_])
    return coordinates_list
```

to get the desired result:

```
function result
nearest neighbors of 2
[0, 0] = 1
[0, 2] = 3
[1, 1] = 5
```

Comment: I've finally understood this code thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you could list all "admissible" displacements explicitly:

```
for dx, dy in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]:
    x_ = min(MAP_WIDTH, max(0, map_x + dx))
    y_ = min(MAP_HEIGHT, max(0, map_y + dy))

    if (map_x, map_y) == (x_, y_):
        continue

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For a problem with such as small number of possibilities, I would just spell them all out and pre-compute the function results for every position. That way the function can be eliminated and the problem reduced to doing simple table look-up operation.

Here's what I mean:

```
nnlist = [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]

MAP_WIDTH = len(nnlist[0])
MAP_HEIGHT = len(nnlist)

nearest_neighbors = {}  # is now a dictionary
for x in range(MAP_WIDTH):
    for y in range(MAP_HEIGHT):
        neighbors = [[nx, ny] for nx, ny in [(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)]
                                  if -1 < nx < MAP_WIDTH and -1 < ny < MAP_HEIGHT]
        nearest_neighbors[(x, y)] = neighbors

print "look-up result"
print "nearest neighbors of", nnlist[0][1]
nearest_neighbor_coordinates_list = nearest_neighbors[(0, 1)]

for coordinates in nearest_neighbor_coordinates_list:
    print coordinates, "=", nnlist[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]]
```